# When I build a representative matrix, I don't understand when to "transpose" its components

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, transpose

From my understanding when I build a representative matrix for a linear transformation I take the transformations product as a linear combination of the bases vectors and place it transposed as the column of the matrix. I accidentally thought that a check for linear dependancy in which the vectors were taken as rows constituted a representative matrix - which they didn't.
 here are two examples -  I didn't understand the approach to one as opposed to the other.
 https://ibb.co/tz4TSbx
 https://ibb.co/PGXFhCQ

Edit - clarification: I didn't understand why when writing ImT as is done in the comments we take the vectors as columns  while in the solution added below now we use them as rows. 
https://ibb.co/HtrR8bN

Comment: to clarify, I have a grasp on the workflow but this specific point eludes me. In the examples above I am asked to find the rep mat of ImT, I can also link the solutions if asked.

Comment: I don't really see the common point between those two examples. None of them involves a representative matrix as far as I can see. The first one is a linear function that sends a degree 2 polynomial to a scalar, and the second one sends a quadruple of scalars to a matrix.

Comment: In the examples I'm asked to construct the representative matrix of ImT. The problem I'm facing is that I don't quite understand the specific step after taking the products of the basis vectors after T and expressing them as a linear transformation, the step is constructing the matrix itself - I don't understand when to take the products and use them as columns and when as rows, I also don't understand the difference between working with a b c d (in the standard bases shortcut) vs working with 1, x, x^2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example was to check linear dependancy and not to make a rep matrix, so in that case we do take it as rows and not columns, while when we do work on rep. matrices we always take them as columns. I was confused - hope I didn't mislead anybody or caused to much headaches

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the relation between the first and second picture, since the representative matrix of $T$ should be $3\times3$ (it acts on a three-dimensional vector space). But let's see how to derive the representative matrix of $T$ from the first picture you sent:

Let $T$ be a linear transformation. The representative matrix $A$ of $T$ is built as such:

The $i-$th column of $A$ corresponds to the image of the $i-th$ basis vector by $T$.

For example, as in your picture, let $T: a+bx+cx^2 \mapsto (-2a + b -2c) + (-a -2c)x + (-a + b -3c)x^2$

Your vector space is the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$, so a basis is $\{1, x, x^2\}$.

We can see that $T(1) = -2 - x - x^2$, which in the above basis can be written $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Similarly, $T(x) = 1 + x^2$, which can be written $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. And $T(x^2)$ is $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$.

So the representative matrix of $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 & -2 \\ -1 & 0 & -2 \\ -1 & 1 & -3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This can probably shortened and given as a comment, as a request for clarification. It doesn't really answer the question (I don't think; I don't really understand what the question is. This is a reason to vote to close/ask for clarification.)

Comment: I don't understand though why in this example its written as a column vector while in another example if you work in a specific manner its written as rows which construct the same matrix - my point being I don't specifically understand why the final step is written as such

Comment: Well, to be honest, it's common to abuse the notation and first write the vectors as rows when computing them, then stacking them vertically, so I wouldn't worry too much about that. What you need to remember is that the $i-$th column of the matrix is the image of the $i-$th basis vector.

Comment: If you wanna get more familiar with those notions, I **strongly** recommend 3b1b's series of videos on linear algebra. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab In particular, the first 3 or 4 videos explain how matrices are constructed, and why they multiply the way they do. If you're learning about linear algebra, it's definitely a must :)

Comment: i think my problem is more fundemental - when i construct representative matrices i sometimes do them transposed because I don't understand wether or not to take them as rows or columns - in the first example which you've answered we took them as columns, but in the second ones solution which i posted we take them as rows and I don't understand when/why we do that - I think its about the technique used and less about notation errors

Comment: Well, without more context about the exercise I can't help you much :/ Do you have the original exercise?

Comment: Its in hebrew so its quite hard to translate, but I'm given in both cases a linear transformation - which I need to write its ImT as a matrix, the problem I'm facing is that in the first case (which you've solved) we input the vectors as columns, while in the other questions solution (which I've added above - take a look) we input the vectors as rows - I don't understand when to do which.